# Changing user $HOME to $ORACLE_BASE

Tags: oracle, unix

Currently we have following settings::

- $HOME(home dir for OS user oracle) - **/export/home/oracle**
- $ORACLE_BASE - **/opt/oracle**
- $ORACLE_HOME - **/opt/oracle/19.3.0**

  1. Is it advisable to change $HOME from /export/home/oracle to /opt/oracle which is $ORACLE_BASE. Any reasons?

Comment: Just keep in mind that when $ORACLE_BASE get full your Db will stop. So you must not upload huge files into your $HOME

Comment: Personally, I'd leave the $HOME at its OS default - /home/<username>.  What do you think you are gaining by having it anywhere else? And I'd expect your ORACLE_HOME to be one level deeper - /opt/oracle/19.3.0/dbhome_1.

Answer (score 1):

Your $ORACLE_HOME contains your RDBMS software and should usually be separate from the home of the software owner.  Nothing else should be in $ORACLE_HOME except software products, patches, diagnostics and OraInventory, as you need to keep careful control of the space used by $ORACLE_HOME. You do not want this filling up as it can affect your database running.

Remember also to have soft links in the diagnostics folder so that Oracle does not write audit files and trace dumps etc. into $ORACLE_HOME. Your trace and diagnostics folder should also be on a different mount point to $ORACLE_HOME.